# PHP cannot find filepaths

Tags: php

I am making a file-mover with a input for filename(using HTML forms). I keep getting 'The system cannot find the path specified.' even with the correct file path. This is on windows 7 In PHP 5.4.30.

I have tried messing around with the file path structure. Trying all different forms,absolute, local, full path, ect. I have tried also with copy(), and move_uploaded_file()

```
<?php
$fn = $_POST['value'];
$con_dir = '/content';
$up_dir = '/uploads';
rename('$up_dir/$fn', '$con_dir/$fn');
?>
```

I expect the file to be moved, but instead I get the 'The system cannot find the path specified.' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, it should be `rename("$up_dir/$fn", "$con_dir/$fn");`.

Also make sure that $fn is a valid filename.

Comment: after changing the code to this the error log reads, "rename(/uploads/t.txt,/content/t.txt): The system cannot find the path specified.", Instead of "rename($up_dir/$fn,$con_dir/$fn): The system cannot find the path specified."(t.txt is a test file). other than this nothing new happened. If it helps, all the error codes are code: 3